# Forking a yarn workspace using lerna and publishing 2 packages under the company namespace

Tags: javascript, typescript, lerna, git-fork, yarn-workspaces

Given a repo using yarn workspace and lerna. This workspace have two packages main-pack and sub-pack. The main-pack does reference sub-pack. I want to fork it and publish a patch on npm under my organisation name (ex: @myorg/main-pack and @myorg/sub-pack).

- I want to avoid having my @myorg/main-pack referencing the official sub-pack.
- I want to minimize code change and for example, I want the typescript files in main-pack to still import sub-pack and avoid changing them to @myorg/sub-pack.

I feel like I am missing something and it should be easy to patch and publish multiple packages with yarn workspace. Maybe something with Lerna or a special publish step?

I tried the npm alias `"sub-pack": "npm:@myorg/sub-pack@*"` but it seems to be conflicting with yarn workspace which usually expect `"sub-pack": "*"` as a workspace reference.

Answer (score 1):

You should try with Yarn/pnpm `workspace:*` protocol, when used, it will enforce the use of local code instead of trying to fetch it from npm (which is what `*` would do). I'm pretty sure that protocol was invented to solve issues similar to yours. For example take a look at pnpm [`workspace:` protocol](https://pnpm.io/workspaces#workspace-protocol-workspace) docs. I just wrote 2min ago a similar answer in this other SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77304073/1212166), the question is different but the answer would be similar. This protocol is also supported by both newer versions of Lerna & [Lerna-Lite](https://github.com/lerna-lite/lerna-lite) (the latter is preferred if you're not using Nx, however if you are using Nx then probably best to stick with Lerna)